# How to unload Relationship collection in spring data?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have entity `Participant`

```
public class Participant extends AbstractParticipant
{
    ...

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "participant")
    private List<MediaCallParticipant> mediaCallParticipant = new LinkedList<>();
    
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "participant")
    private List<AudioCallParticipant> audioCallParticipant = new LinkedList<>();
}
```

I'm writing a test. Where I do `participantRepository.findOne(...)`
But in the test I can't get a LazyLoadException with `participant.getAudioCallParticipant()` or `participant.getMediaCallParticipant()`.
I have written code that is ready to Lazy exception. but this collections are always load in entity.
Is it possible to somehow manually "unload" the collections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is supposed to work.
If you need to do this in a test, try this code

```java
        // init here another context

        TestTransaction.start();
        participant = participantRepository.findOne(participant);
        getSessionFactory().getStatistics().clear();
        participant.getMediaCallParticipant();

        //assert
        assertThat(getStatistics().getPrepareStatementCount(),is(1L));
```

Answer (score 0):

Detach entity or close the session before call `participant.getAudioCallParticipant()` (you will get the same result).
Ths is because lazy associations cannot be fetched for the detached entities.

Comment: When I turn off the connection, the "Participant" already has both collections. When I disconnected the connection using `SessionFactory.close()` I can also get all the collections using getters

Comment: Did you trace executed sql?

Comment: yes. nothing new

Comment: I meant, did you notice eager loading of relatations data?
Maybe add full model, test code and traced sql generated by test code in OP can help people get a complete view of problem and lead to a solution

Comment: @WBLord as Luca already said, we are going to need more code as that is definitely not usual behavior. You should definitely be getting a `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: [entity], could not initialize proxy - the owning Session was closed` when trying to load lazy load something without an active transaction/session